# How to make a trait function return the implementor type?

Tags: rust, traits

Building off of this example:

```rust
// traits
trait MessageHandler {
    fn handle_message(&self, message: String) -> String;
}

trait ConnectionHandler {
    fn toggle_connection(self) -> Box<dyn ConnectionHandler>;
}

trait MultiHandler: MessageHandler + ConnectionHandler {}
impl<T: MessageHandler + ConnectionHandler> MultiHandler for T {}
```

```rust
// state_machine
struct StateMachine<S> {
    state: S
}

struct Disconnected {}
struct Connected {}

impl MessageHandler for StateMachine<Disconnected> {
    fn handle_message(&self, message: String) -> String {
        return format!("[Disconnected] Handled: {}", message)
    }
}

impl ConnectionHandler for StateMachine<Disconnected> {
    fn toggle_connection(self) -> Box<dyn ConnectionHandler> {
        return Box::new(StateMachine { state: Connected {} });
    }
}

impl MessageHandler for StateMachine<Connected> {
    fn handle_message(&self, message: String) -> String {
        return format!("[Connected] Handled: {}", message)
    }
}

impl ConnectionHandler for StateMachine<Connected> {
    fn toggle_connection(self) -> Box<dyn ConnectionHandler> {
        return Box::new(StateMachine { state: Disconnected {} });
    }
}
```

The problem lies in `App::toggle_connection`, in the code below. As the traits are currently specified, this function returns a `Box<dyn ConnectionHandler>`, while it expects a `Box<dyn MultiHandler>`.

You can find the error message below the code.

```rust
// app
struct App {
    multi_handler: Box<dyn MultiHandler>
}

impl App {
    fn new() -> App {
        return App { multi_handler: Box::new(StateMachine { state: Disconnected {} }) }
    }

    fn parse_message(&self, message: String) {
        println!("{}", self.multi_handler.handle_message(message))
    }

    fn toggle_connection(&mut self) {
        self.multi_handler = self.multi_handler.toggle_connection()
    }
}
```

```
// error message
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:60:30
   |
60 |         self.multi_handler = self.multi_handler.toggle_connection()
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `MultiHandler`, found trait `ConnectionHandler`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<(dyn MultiHandler + 'static)>`
              found struct `Box<(dyn ConnectionHandler + 'static)>`
help: try removing the method call
   |
60 -         self.multi_handler = self.multi_handler.toggle_connection()
60 +         self.multi_handler = self.multi_handler
   |
```

How can I make the `handle_connection` method return the same type as the caller?

E.g.: If the calling instance is `ConnectionHandler` then return `Box<dyn ConnectionHandler>`, if it's `MultiHandler` then return `Box<dyn MultiHandler>`.

IIRC, it's possible to do this with associated types. Are there different ways to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give an example how these traits should be used? Do you mean `self` when referring to `caller`? In this case, would it helf to change the signature to `fn handle_connection(self) -> Box<Self>;`?

Comment: @CoronA that makes the trait non object save though, it's impossible to tell if that matters though.

Comment: Edited the code sample to match the actual problem

Comment: It's always `MultiHandler`, because that's how you store it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's not what I get. I updated the code samples to include a full code sample, and the compilation error message.